# Generate HTML files in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js

I have a Scala.js project with an `index.html` file. Currently I use a structure like in [Scala.js example](https://github.com/sjrd/scala-js-example-app), with two different `index.html` files for `fullOptJS` and `fastOptJS` builds. However I would like to DRY this somehow.

I think it should be possible to generate both `index.html` and `index-fastopt.html` from a common source template using a simple Scala code doing the substitution of the variable parts. Perhaps one could achieve this using [Generating sources and resources](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Howto/generatefiles.html), but I am unsure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a checkout of the scala.js example project and modified it a little bit.

First, edit `index.html` and replace the following lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./target/scala-2.11/example-opt.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./target/scala-2.11/example-launcher.js"></script>
```

with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{example.js}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="example-launcher.js"></script>
```

Next, add the following lines in build.sbt:

```scala
def generateIndexTask(suffix: String) = Def.task {
  val source = baseDirectory.value / "index.html"
  val target = (crossTarget in Compile).value / "index.html"
  val log = streams.value.log
  IO.writeLines(target,
    IO.readLines(source).map {
      line => line.replace("{{example.js}}", s"example-$suffix.js")
    }
  )

  log.info(s"generate with suffix: $suffix")
}

(fastOptJS in Compile) <<= (fastOptJS in Compile).dependsOn(generateIndexTask("fastopt"))
(fullOptJS in Compile) <<= (fullOptJS in Compile).dependsOn(generateIndexTask("opt"))
```

The generated index.html will be located at the sample place as the generate .js files: `./target/scala-2.11`

You should probably adjust the file paths to your own use.

For my own projects, I use another structure with a sbt-web project at the top level to manage all assets and the scala-js code in a sub-project that exports it's code as a webjar. It's more flexible.

Comment: Work fine. The index.html output file name should be probably different for fast/full Opt, though.

Comment: To do this, just replace in the target value: `"index.html"` with `s"index-$suffix.html"`. For my personal taste, I prefer always loading the same file, and let the build system handle the correct generation.